# Modifying Tomcat Connector settings on Heroku

Tags: tomcat, heroku, webapp-runner

The Heroku's `webapp-runner.jar` runs on Tomcat and the default Tomcat `maxPostSize` is `2MB`. I need to increase this value but have no idea how can I do that.

I see no parameter for this setting in https://github.com/jsimone/webapp-runner#options (this is the runner to which official Heroku documentation points to). There is a `maxPostSize` connector option in the Tomcat documentation (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html ) but I have no idea how can I pass it to `webapp-runner`.

In act of desperation I tried setting `--maxPostSize` in `WEBAPP_RUNNER_OPTS` but when I start the app I am getting:

```
  Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: 
  Unknown option: --maxPostSize=8388608
```

Although I am trying to increase max post size, this question is relevant to any other Tomcat Connector parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
 heroku config:set WEBAPP_RUNNER_OPTS="-AmaxPostSize=12582912"
```

You must have a relatively recent version of webrunner referenced, though .